# Any open source web based X509 PKI tool?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, x509

Want to setup a CA, but it's hard to find a good web based X509 PKI tool, any recommend?

Comment: Define "good", for your purposes.

Answer (score 7):

As Dom said you can use [EJBCA](http://www.ejbca.org/), but it's a PITA to set up (it uses tomcat, you have to meddle with the java key store, and the setup scripts are somewhat broken). I gave up on it.
Then there is [openxpki](http://www.openxpki.org), but the [documentation](http://openxpki.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is so lacking that I gave up on that as well (the config files are a labyrinth, after 6 hours of meddling with my setup and reading the docs I still have no idea of how to set up users).
openxpki was started because developers from the [OpenCA](http://www.openca.org/projects/openca/) project were in disagreement with the original author of the project (if I remember correctly). I couldn't figure out how to install OpenCA on debian, so I gave up on that as well.
The author of [openWebPKI](http://www.cymc.online.fr/openwebpki/) requires you to send him an **email** to obtain the source code for the web interface, this doesn't really instill confidence either.

Right now I am simply using some shell scripts (which sucks, big time).

Answer (score 1):

[http://www.cymc.online.fr/openwebpki/](http://www.cymc.online.fr/openwebpki/]),
http://www.ejbca.org/ are maybe what your are looking for. I never used them.